# Call module.Functionname from user input

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to call module(.)functionname from a image lirary upon user input.
For instance a user types in
"GaussianBlurr"

I want to be able to replace (*ImagerFilter.user_input*) and call that filter.(Line 3)

```
def ImageFilterUsingPil():
    im = Image.open('hotdog.jpg')
    im.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur) # instead im.filter(ImageFilter.user_input)
    im.save('hotdog.png')
```

Also I tried this

```
user_input = 'GaussianBlur'
def ImageFilterUsingPil():
    im = Image.open('hotdog.jpg')
    im.filter(ImageFilter.user_input) 
    im.save('hotdog.png')
```

it threw me `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'user_input'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking to use [getattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) here.

```
call = getattr(ImageFilter, user_input)
call()
```

More explicit to your code, you can do this:

```
im.filter(getattr(ImageFilter, user_input)())
```

Simple example:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     @classmethod
...     def bar(cls):
...         print('hello')
...
>>> getattr(Foo, 'bar')()
hello
```

However, you might want to make sure you handle exceptions for when you send something invalid. So, you should probably wrap your attempt to call the method with a `try/except`.

```
>>> try:
...     getattr(Foo, 'bar')()
... except AttributeError:
...     # do exception handling here
```

You could also assign a default as `None` (Personally I would rather ([EAFP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python)) and then check to see if it is not `None` before calling it:

```
call = getattr(ImageFilter, user_input, None)
if call:
    call()
else:
    # do fail logic here
```

Comment: Would my syntax be like this?     im.filter(getattr(ImageFilter.user_input))

Comment: @BiplovDahal Almost. You have to actually call it. `im.filter(getattr(ImageFilter.user_input)())`

Comment: @BiplovDahal Woops, I had a type. Do you not put command in ImageFilter,user_input instead of ImageFilter.user_input?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. My answer is giving you exactly what to do. Does it not work?

Comment: @BiplovDahal if this solution helped you, please consider marking it as accepted in order to help other readers know this solved your problem.